# ax.text() not behaving like I think it should :(

Tags: python, matplotlib

This driving me nuts. I'm using Jupyter-Lab to render this chart and add text.

Why does the text push the chart around? It should go over ax1 - right?

I know this is something dumb, but please help!

```
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=5, figsize=(6,10))

# Useful lists
axes = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5]
sides = ['left','bottom','right','top']

#Style
style.use('default')
style.use('ggplot')

# Loop to set the attributes
for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(euro_to_pound['time'], euro_to_pound['uk_pound'], alpha=0.3, color='grey')
    ax.set(facecolor='white')
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.tick_params(bottom=0, left=0) 
    for side in sides:
        ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)

# Create Sections
ax1.plot(blair_slice['uk_pound'], alpha=1,color='#DC241f')
ax2.plot(brown_slice['uk_pound'], alpha=1,color='#DC241f')
ax3.plot(cameron_slice['uk_pound'], alpha=1,color='#0087DC')
ax4.plot(may_slice['uk_pound'], alpha=1,color='#0087DC')
ax5.plot(johnson_slice['uk_pound'], alpha=1,color='#0087DC')

ax1.text(1, 1, s='Tony Blair', color='#DC241f', weight='bold')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect you want to add the text using `axes` coordinates, rather than `data` coordinates. Try adding the kwarg `transform=ax1.transAxes` to the `ax1.text()` command

Comment: Thanks @tmdavison, that did work for the ax.text() but the same problem no happens with the ax.axvline() and anything similar, and they don't take a transform kwarg.

I have made other charts where this is not a problem...there must be something in the way I am creating this chart, the data I'm using, or the way I'm calling ax.plot() but I have no idea what!

Comment: In `axvline`, the `x` position is in data coordinates, so you should provide a date/time value as `x` position.

Comment: @luuk, that works too! I thought axvline worked on datapoints, but I guess if I've plotted on time, then that's why.

I still have no idea why I have to do this in this chart, but not in the others I have done, but this is definitely working.